# Translate SPARQL query to SQL query

Tags: sql, sqlite, sparql

I am learning database management. One task is to be able to convert SPARQL query by hand. I was confused about the `FROM` clause in queries and how to identify them.

In the query below `SELECT` is straight forward but what determines the `FROM` and `WHERE` clause.

Database format: `Triples(s text, p text, o text)`

```
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
SELECT ?place
WHERE {

    dbr:Lionel_Messi dbo:birthPlace ?place 
}
```

My understanding:

```
SELECT dbo:birthPlace
FROM dbr:Lionel_Messi
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the database schema one decides for to store the triples `(s p o)`. The most common and easiest ones are

1. a single table with columns for `s`, `p` and `o`.
2. property tables, i.e. one table for each property `p` with columns `s` and `o`

For option 1, the query could look like

```
SELECT T.o
FROM triples T
WHERE T.s = "dbr:Lionel_Messi" AND T.p = "dbo:birthPlace"
```

For option 2, it could be something like

```
SELECT T.o
FROM dbo:birthPlace T
WHERE T.s = "dbr:Lionel_Messi"
```

Note, that I'm showing a simplified version here, i.e. naming convention of tables and prefix resolving would have to be done when creating the tables and loading the data (e.g. storing full URIs)